# Android Things GPS ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gps, android-things, adafruit

I am using the Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout v3 with Android Things on a raspberry Pi 3. Using the following driver:

https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps

I am trying to show the current location in a TextView when a button is pressed.
I can log the NMEA messages but get frequent Invalid GSV Messages. It also crashes quite quickly with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Can somebody help please?

Here is the log:

> :33:08.782 2536-2536/com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps I/zygote: Deoptimizing void com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaParser.handleSatelliteData(java.lang.String[]) due to block bounds check elimination
>   06-19 08:33:08.783 2536-2536/com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-19 08:33:08.791 2536-2536/com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps, PID: 2536
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=19
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaParser.handleSatelliteData(NmeaParser.java:199)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaParser.processMessageFrame(NmeaParser.java:101)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.handleFrameEnd(NmeaGpsModule.java:206)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.processBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:175)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.readUartBuffer(NmeaGpsModule.java:160)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule.access$000(NmeaGpsModule.java:41)
>           at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps.NmeaGpsModule$1.onUartDeviceDataAvailable(NmeaGpsModule.java:138)
>           at com.google.android.things.pio.UartDeviceImpl$UartDeviceCallbackDispatch.dispatchInterruptEvent(UartDeviceImpl.java:250)
>           at com.google.android.things.pio.CallbackDispatch.onFileDescriptorEvents(CallbackDispatch.java:149)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.dispatchEvents(MessageQueue.java:284)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   06-19 08:33:08.804 2536-2536/com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.gps I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2536 SIG: 9

UPDATE:

After changing the NmeaParser from 19 to 2 here:

```
// Parse the satellites in this message
for (int i = 4; i < 2; i += 4) {
    if (!nmea[i].isEmpty()) {
        Satellite sat = new Satellite();
        sat.svid = Integer.parseInt(nmea[i]);
        sat.elevation = parseTrackAngle(nmea[i+1]);
        sat.azimuth = parseTrackAngle(nmea[i+2]);
        sat.snr = parseSignal(nmea[i+3]);

        mSatellites.put(sat.svid, sat);
    }
}
```

Im not getting the crash but I am still getting Invalid GSV messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NmeaParser` in the GPS driver was incorrectly handling GSV messages that were variable length. We just released a new v1.1 of the driver that fixes the parsing. You should update your app to point to the latest artifact:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-gps:1.1'
```